# Como colocar anuncios da AdMob no Genexus?

Tags: android, ios, genexus, admob

Estou tentando colocar anúncios em meu aplicativo feito e Genexus, utilizando a AdMob, [segui o tutorial](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Ads%20%28Advertising%29), mas os anúncios não aparecem no aplicativo. Alguém já fez isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa se cadastrar no site da adMob, e entrar com sua conta do Google de desenvolvedor, depois é só seguir esses passos:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Já fiz isso, e tbm coloquei o sdk da admob no meu app, mas nenhum anuncio é mostrado no app